# Как из AutoCompleteTextView сохранить данные в переменную?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, не могу сообразить, как из `AutoCompleteTextView` сохранить введённый текст в переменную?

```
public void onClickPhoto(View view) {
    mAutoComplete.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView /*текст по идеи должен с неё попадать*/.VISIBLE);
    name = mAutoComplete.getText().toString();// сюда 
    if (name != null) { }
```

Comment: какие именно данные?

Comment: @metalurgus string

Comment: Какой string? Введенный текст?

Comment: @metalurgus да всё верно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Точно так же, как и из любого другого `TextView`:

```
String text = autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
```

Разве это не очевидно?

Comment: Верно, но что тогда я делаю не так текст в итоге у меня в переменную не попадает. Объявляю в поле класса переменную String name; далее идёт метод в котором данная конструкция используется `public void onClickPhoto(View view) {

        mAutoComplete.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.VISIBLE);//текст по идеи должен с неё попадать
        name = mAutoComplete.getText().toString();// сюда

        if (name != null) { }` а на выходе в переменной нет ни чего.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: @VargSieg, что именно значить "ничего"? `null` или пустая строка

Comment: @metalurgus пустая строка

Comment: @VargSieg, а вы уверены, что mAutoComplete не пустой?

Answer (score 4):

[AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) является наследником [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), который в свою очередь наследуется от [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

У TextView есть метод [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) для получения текущего отображаемого текста.